# Any good wrappers/libraries for Google CHarts with PHP?

Tags: php, google-visualization

I see alot of them around, but short of comparing them all it might be quicker to code my own.

Unless someone already has done an evaluation & can recommend "the best" ...

(or has decided that PChart is better :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gChartPHP](http://code.google.com/p/gchartphp/), have a read through the documentation. Should have what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 Thanks, http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-04/16-google_chart_api_via_php  compares a few & says that thaon e" nearly covers the whole API"

Comment: I have acepted this as answer, because it does answer the question - gChartPhp seems to be - currently - the best out there. FWIW, though, I am going to roll my own (that way I don't have to wait on updates).